# On click, add class until checkbox/label clicked off

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

## Context:

I'm styling a check-box using sprite-sheet and jQuery.

I want the "focus" state to behave exactly like the checkboxes featured on this [free HTML5 template](http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/spectral/elements.html#demo-name):

By "focus"/"blur", I'm referring to the colored border around the checkbox that:

1. ...appears on tab into checkbox, click on checkbox or click on label.
2. ...disappears on tab out of checkbox, click out of checkbox or click off of label.

## My Code:

Thus far, I've only achieved the described "focus"/"blur" on tabbing in/out of the checkbox.

**As JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/k9mgh8rz/4/

**As HTML Page**:

(CDN scripts wouldn't load when posting as Stack Overflow snippet).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"] {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    input[type="text"]:focus,
    input[type="password"]:focus {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }

    label {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .forgetmenot span {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 15px;
      position: relative;
      top: 3px;
    }

    /* iCheck Plugin (Skin for check-box)
    ----------------------------------- */

    .icheckbox_minimal {
      display: inline-block;
      *display: inline;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background: url(http://s10.postimg.org/lzj62spk5/check_boxes.png) no-repeat;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .icheckbox_minimal {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }

    .icheckbox_minimal.checked {
      background-position: -60px 0;
    }

    .icheckbox_minimal.focus {
      background-position: -30px 0;
    }

    .icheckbox_minimal.checked.focus {
      background-position: -90px 0;
    }

    /* HiDPI support */

    @media (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
    (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
    (min-resolution: 120dpi),
    (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
      .icheckbox_minimal {
        background-image: url(http://s16.postimg.org/k51empanp/check_boxes_2x.png);
        -webkit-background-size: 200px 20px;
        background-size: 200px 20px;
      }
    }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <!--Mark-up cannot be edited for the purposes of the required solution.-->

    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Username<br>
            <input class="input" id="user_login" name="log" size="20" type="text" value="">
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Password<br>
            <input class="input" id="user_pass" name="pwd" size="20" type="password" value="">
        </label>
    </p>

    <p class="forgetmenot">
        <label for="rememberme">
            <input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever"> Remember Me
        </label>
    </p>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.1/icheck.js"></script> 
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //Add span for styling.
      $('#rememberme').each(function() {
        $(this.nextSibling).wrap('<span><\/span>');
      });
      //Apply iCheck
      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal'
      });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

## My question:

Using the above JSFiddle, modifying only jQuery and CSS (but not the mark-up), how can I achieve the described "focus"/"blur" for click in/out of checkbox and click on/off of label?

Comment: I don't really get your explanation of 'focus' and 'blur'. What tab are you talking about? EDIT: nvm I get it now.

Comment: @Glubus "Tab in to" and "tab out of" refer to the keyboard inputs that trigger the focusing and blurring of native checkboxes. To reproduce, click into one of text text boxes and press tab until you reach the checkbox. You'll observe the border of the checkbox changes from black to red.

Comment: I gotta go now, i'll get back to this when I get some more time tonight.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
  $('input').on('click change', function()
  {
     $('input').css('border-color', 'black'); // reset all inputs to black
     $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); // define the current one as red
  });
```

Comment: I've experimented with your suggestion but the event won't trigger: http://pastebin.com/PyAd2u2A